# Modify SharePoint sandbox manifest.xml

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I need to modify the SharePoint sandbox manifest.xml. Can any one help me with how I can do this?

Comment: Hi! We need some more information, what is it you need to change in the manifest? And what is the objective?

Comment: Hi Have SharePoint 2010 sandbox solution which I required to deploy it in online SharePoint 2013 I came to knew we required to change the Hive folder to 15 from manifest file from below link http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/24/deploy-sharepoint-2010-solutions-in-sharepoint-2013/ .Can you help me how can I achieve this or is there better way to deploy the solution to Online SharePoint 2013

Comment: The only relevant part regarding sandboxed solutions from that link is: "Sandbox solutions are upgraded with the Content databases." Which means that you do not have to upgrade them yourself I guess

Comment: Hi Robert Thanks for your imp info. I deployed the sandbox of SharePoint 2010 and it is working fine. I would like to forcefully put the solution into 15 hive folder. So can you please help me how can I edit the manifest.xml file of sandbox solution

Comment: Nothing in a sandboxed solution will end up in the hive (since deploying files to layouts etc should not be done in a sandboxed solution). Also note that sandboxed solutions containing server side code is deprecated from 2013

Comment: Thank you very Robert. But I had written the Sandbox Visual Web-Part and I am able to perform the crude operations.

Comment: I would still advice you to embrace the new development pattern for 2013 to make it future-proof :) but of course that is up to you!